# Reshaping data to wide without quantitative data

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I think I understand general reshaping. However, I have data that needs to be reshaped to wide format, but I don't want to show scores or quantitative data indexed by another variable.

Instead, I want to switch one variable from a single variable to five variables based on its values. No other variables should be indexed. I want the values of the one variable to form the other five variables, and values of those variables should simply be the same as their variable names.

I've included an example of a before and after.

Data:

```
> dput(ansscales3)

structure(list(ATID = c(33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33), AnswerTypeDesc = c("VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", 
"VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", 
"VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD", "VS|S|SD|VD"
), AValue = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4), ScaleValue = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1), ADesc = c("Very Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Somewhat Dissatisfied", "Very Dissatisfied", "Very Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Somewhat Dissatisfied", "Very Dissatisfied", "Somewhat Dissatisfied", 
"Very Dissatisfied", "Very Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very Satisfied"
), AOrder = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1), StatGroup = c("AdjN", 
"AdjN", "AdjN", "AdjN", "N", "N", "N", "N", "PctNeg", "PctNeg", 
"PctPos", "PctPos", "TopBox"), Cycles = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)), .Names = c("ATID", "AnswerTypeDesc", 
"AValue", "ScaleValue", "ADesc", "AOrder", "StatGroup", "Cycles"
), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Reshape into:

```
> dput(atids1)

structure(list(ATID = c(33, 33, 33, 33), AnswerTypeDesc = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "VS|S|SD|VD", class = "factor"), AValue = c(4, 
3, 2, 1), ScaleValue = c(1, 2, 3, 4), ADesc = c("Very Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Somewhat Dissatisfied", "Very Dissatisfied"), AOrder = c(1, 
2, 3, 4), Cycles = c(11, 11, 11, 11), N = c("N", "N", "N", "N"
), AdjN = c("AdjN", "AdjN", "AdjN", "AdjN"), PctPos = c("PctPos", 
"PctPos", "", ""), PctNeg = c("", "", "PctNeg", "PctNeg"), TopBox = c("TopBox", 
"", "", "")), .Names = c("ATID", "AnswerTypeDesc", "AValue", 
"ScaleValue", "ADesc", "AOrder", "Cycles", "N", "AdjN", "PctPos", 
"PctNeg", "TopBox"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm sure this is simple but unfortunately I haven't been able to figure it out using the reshape method.

Comment: I've edited, with `fill = ""`. Not the output is exactly the same as the desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `reshape2`

(note: I've loaded `dplyr` to trigger the `%>%` operator but this is just a personal choice of styling code)

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% dcast(... ~ StatGroup, value.var = "StatGroup", fill = "")
  ATID AnswerTypeDesc AValue ScaleValue                 ADesc AOrder Cycles AdjN N PctNeg PctPos TopBox
1   33     VS|S|SD|VD      1          4     Very Dissatisfied      4     11 AdjN N PctNeg              
2   33     VS|S|SD|VD      2          3 Somewhat Dissatisfied      3     11 AdjN N PctNeg              
3   33     VS|S|SD|VD      3          2             Satisfied      2     11 AdjN N        PctPos       
4   33     VS|S|SD|VD      4          1        Very Satisfied      1     11 AdjN N        PctPos TopBox
```

another solution with `tidyr`

```
 library(tidyr)
 dat1 %>% spread(StatGroup, StatGroup, fill = "")
  ATID AnswerTypeDesc AValue ScaleValue                 ADesc AOrder Cycles AdjN N PctNeg PctPos TopBox
1   33     VS|S|SD|VD      1          4     Very Dissatisfied      4     11 AdjN N PctNeg              
2   33     VS|S|SD|VD      2          3 Somewhat Dissatisfied      3     11 AdjN N PctNeg              
3   33     VS|S|SD|VD      3          2             Satisfied      2     11 AdjN N        PctPos       
4   33     VS|S|SD|VD      4          1        Very Satisfied      1     11 AdjN N        PctPos TopBox
```

Comment: Definitely works! All of the fills are replaced with NAs, seems to be due to some issues with the data structure getting messy way deep in the dataset, but thats not really an issue. Much cleaner than using SPSS restructure too!